# line to connect two images dropped on canvas using kineticjs

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have toolbar with multiple images which can be dragged and dropped on the canvas and also movable. 
i want create a button called line to connect the images dropped on canvas using kineticjs

Answer (score 0):

Do this in the click event handler of your button:

```
// assumes i1 & i2 are references your images, 
// this code creates a new line connecting those 2 images

var line=new Kinetic.Line({stroke:'black',points:[i1.x(),i1.y(),i2.x(),i2.y()]});
layer.add(line);
line.moveToBottom();
layer.draw();
```